# Definition of the principal symbol of "endomorphism-type" differential operators

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Consider a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ and, say, the symmetric trace-free square of the cotangent bundle $\odot^2_\circ T^* M$ (and its dual $\odot^2_\circ T M$), and fix a section $u^{ab} \in \odot^2_\circ TM$.

For any section $v \in \odot^2_\circ T^* M$, I am struggling to figure out what the principal symbol is of operators such as
$$v_{ab} \mapsto g_{aa'} g_{bb'} g^{cc'} g^{dd'} v^{a'b'} \nabla_c \nabla_d u_{c'd'}$$
(or, raising and lowering indices using the metric, $u_{ab} \nabla^c \nabla^d v_{cd}$).

Because this is an "endomorphism-type" (not sure of the correct language here) differential operator, in that the operator "moves" indices off of $v$ onto $u$, it's not clear to me how the symbol would be defined. On the other hand, it seems very straightforward to me to define the principal symbol of a differential operator that acts like
$$v_{ab} \mapsto u^{cd} \nabla_c \nabla_d v_{ab}\,.$$
In this case, the principal symbol is the tensor $u$.

How is the principal symbol defined in this (example) case? How is it defined in general for differential operators from one tensor bundle to another, especially when "endomorphism-type" operators are permitted?

Comment: You have written two different things in the definition of your operator... maybe you switched $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Yep. I did. In the first equation, it should have $u^{a'b'}$ and $v_{c'd'}$.

Comment: So it seems that the operator is just the multiplication of $\nabla^a\nabla^bv_{ab}$ with $u^{ab}$, right? In this particular case the symbol should just be whatever the symbol of $v\mapsto \nabla^a\nabla^b v_{ab}$ is. Do you know how to compute this one?

Comment: Yep. I actually probably should have closed this question - it made me uncomfortable that the symbol of an endomorphism-valued differential operator should be a type $(2,2)$ tensor, but it's just what it is.

Comment: I understand perfectly, had the same "problem" myself a while ago (: